# I am hoping to make a Latin motto for a teaching team

Tags: motto

Good day. We are looking to create a motto for a training group for public servants. The motto in English would be "Mentoring guardians of peace". Would this be something like "Docentes custodes pacis"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note the English phrase is ambiguous (are the guardians the mentors, or are they being mentored?). By chance, your Latin version (which is grammatically correct) has the same ambiguity.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel
For "being mentored", would you not have to use passive participle *doctus* instead of active participle *docēns*?

Comment: @Arfrever Not with an implied subject and *custodes* being the object, e.g. in *hi doctores docentes illos custodes pacis*, etc.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel would changing the English version to "Mentoring the guardians of peace" or "Teaching those who guard peace" facilitate the translation to something less ambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

You probably used automatic translation software, and result is expectedly wrong.

English *-ing* is used for 3 unrelated functions: (1) [action noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ing#Etymology_1), (2) [present active participle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ing#Etymology_2) (they were distinct in Old/Middle English, *-in**g*** / *-un**g*** versus *-en**d**e* / *-an**d**(e)* / *-in**d**e*.), (3) [some different nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ing#Etymology_3) irrelevant here.

*docentēs* is plural nominative/vocative/accusative form of Latin participle [*docēns*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/docens#Latin) "teaching, instructing", from verb [*doceō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doceo#Latin) (infinitive *docēre*).

*docentēs custōdēs* or *custōdēs docentēs* (word order is mostly free in Latin) would mean "guardians teaching/instructing" as in "guardians, **who are** teaching/instructing", not "teaching/instructing **of** guardians".

You can use Latin infinitive (here *docēre*) as action noun: "Docēre custōdēs pācis".

Comment: @cmw: Seb has said that the OP's offer, "docentes custodes pacis" is grammatically correct. Arfrever claims that this means, "guardians (who are) teaching," not, "teaching of guardians". Given that a present-participle must agree with the noun it's describing, are both versions correct? To eliminate the ambiguity is the infinitive, "docere", the correct choice?

Comment: @tony "*Docentēs custōdēs pācis*" has 2 possible meanings: (1) "guardians of peace, who are teaching" (when *docentēs* is nominative and *custōdēs* is nominative); (2) "some other persons are teaching guardians of peace" (when *docentēs* is nominative and *custōdēs* is accusative). (If both are treated as accusatives, or as vocatives, then it will be some variation of first meaning.) (You can check their declension tables in Wiktionary if you want. They show that some level of syncretism is present here.) Meaning "teaching of guardians" is not possible for this sentence.

Comment: @tony
Original question contains 「We are looking to create a motto for a training group for public servants. The motto in English would be "Mentoring guardians of peace".」. With the most likely meaning of English sentence, this means that neither of meanings of "*Docentēs custōdēs pācis*" matches desired meaning.

Comment: @tony For action noun with meaning "(act of) teaching", either infinitive or a real noun (e.g. [*doctrīna*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doctrina#Latin)) is needed. Latin noun *doctrīna* can have neutral meaning, but I would avoid it in English community to avoid confusion with English noun [*doctrine*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doctrine#English) which has strong philosophical / theological / ideological / political connotations.

Comment: @tony so then the proper grammatical form would be "Doctrīna custōdēs pācis"? I'm not clear on why there would be an aversion to using this. Can you expand further as to why it should be avoided? I commented above that it might serve better to change the English version of the motto to "Mentoring the guardians of peace" or "Teaching those who guard peace". Would we end up with the same result?

Comment: @Pete
And what exactly are you trying to do with that no longer ambiguous English sentence? E.g. Google Translate is probably quite good for translations between English, French, Spanish, German etc., but for rarer languages like Latin it mostly produces garbage.

Comment: @Pete For Latin sentence with noun *doctrīna*, use form of genitive (and plural here) of noun [*custōs*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/custos#Latin): "*Doctrīna custōdum pācis*".